# should i put all my link inside my sitemap

Tags: seo, sitemap

Normally i'm putting only important link inside my sitemap which right now they are about 3985 and google has indexed 3501 of them.

But the exact number of my links are over 100,000 and with each link there is an image that i show it to my users.

So, should i put all my links including my images inside my sitemap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put every link you want search engines to crawl and index in your sitemap. That's the whole purpose of XML sitemaps, to tell search engines about your pages and images as well. 100,000 links and images are not a lot at all so don't worry about thinking Google will ignore your sitemap or be overwhelmed by it.

Comment: but a visitor that views a sitemap will be overwhelmed. the browser could freeze.

Comment: If you're talking about an HTML sitemap then you would want to break your sitemap down into smaller parts and expand upon it as a user clicks on more and more specific links narrowing down the content they are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You are on the right path. Only put important links in your sitemap file. Fore more information perhaps check out the Google help page on the topic.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184&from=40318&rd=1

I would also check out the following link which describes sitemaps from a Google employee

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30186/are-there-any-clear-indicators-that-my-sitemap-file-is-beneficial